# Which tense to use in “… als ob …” construction

Tags: difference, subjunctive, verb-usage

I don’t know whether to use *Präsens* or *Konjuntiv II* when using the phrase *… als ob …* For example, which of the following is correct?

> Warum tust du so, als ob du ein Affe **bist**?
>
> Warum tust du so, als ob du ein Affe **wärst**?

Comment: _Conjunctivus irrealis_ because he is not => Konjunktiv II.

Comment: The difference is not the tense but the mood.

Comment: Even if the conjunctive form (wärst) is correct, in spoken language the first is also widely used. I am wondering if it will be allowed soon. ;-)

Comment: @CarstenS Why do you not edit the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second sentence is correct. For expressing something in the *[Irrealis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis#Deutsche_Sprache)* you need a *Konjunktiv*.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/nebensaetze-mit-als-ob-als-wenn-wie-wenn) states that these kind of *als-ob-Irrealis* sentences can also be used with *Konjunktiv I* although *Konjunktiv II* is more common. So both these sentences are correct:

> - Warum tust du so, **als ob** du ein Affe **wärst**? *[Konjunktiv II]*
> - Warum tust du so, **als ob** du ein Affe **seist**? *[Konjunktiv I]*

Also, I want to point out that for the *Irrealis* you can just omit the *ob*. Where I come from in western Austria this form is considered rather formal compared to the *als ob* version, but it is definitely used in daily speech.

Use it like this:

> - Warum tust du so, **als wärst** du ein Affe? *[Konjunktiv II]*

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is correct.

The phrase *... als ob ...* indicates that something is **not** the stated way, but we pretend it were.

> Lass uns so tun, als ob wir reich wären.
>   Du siehst aus, als ob Du gerade aufgewacht wärst.

In your example: The person addressed is not a monkey, but he behaves like one.

---

Just to add to the comment made by "user unknown". You **can** use Konjunktiv I to express the same thing:

> Lass uns so tun, als ob wir reich seien

This works for all the above sentences. But **usually**, to express the irrealis, Konjunktiv II is used.

Comment: Warum nicht "Lass uns so tun, als ob wir reich seien"?

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe meine Antwort bearbeitet.

Comment: Because they are not, so it has to be _wären_ (Konjuntiv II).

Comment: @Ingmar: Und Konjunktiv 1 für indirekte Rede? Etwa: Klaus sagt, dass Peter ein Affe sei.

Comment: @userunknown Eher: _Klaus sagt, dass Peter sich wie ein Affe benehme._ Oder: _Klaus sagt, Peter benehme sich, als ob er ein Affe wäre._

Comment: @Ingmar: Wenn Klaus sagt: "Peter ist ein Affe", dann sagt Klaus, das Peter ein Affe sei. Sagt Klaus "Peter benimmt sich wie ein Affe", dann sagt Klaus, dass sich Peter wie ein Affe benehme.

Comment: Das stimmt für den Fall, dass der in der indirekten Rede wiedergegebene Satz lautet "... ist ein Affe". Da hier aber schon die Prämisse falsch ist (Peter ist eben kein Affe, sondern ein Mensch) bin von einem "... benimmt sich wie ein Affe" o.ä. ausgegangen.